# Get the calling component of TPopupMenu

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey, vcl, popupmenu

I have a TStringGrid, that has a TPopupMenu connected.
By clicking one event of the popup menu, I would like to get the calling component. Is that possible?

Background:
It is a bigger project, every form has a "BasicForm" I can inherited from. So I would like to provide a "default popup menu" for grids that have stuff like Copy, Select, and so on in it. In the inherited form I only match the grid (if exists) with that popup and I'm done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you are looking for the *PopupComponent* property of TPopupMenu:
[Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.PopupComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.PopupComponent)

> Indicates the component that last displayed the popup menu in response
> to a right mouse click.
>
> Read PopupComponent to determine which control is currently using the
> popup menu. In applications where multiple controls share the same
> pop-up menu, use PopupComponent to determine which of them displayed
> the menu.
>
> Set PopupComponent to associate a control with the menu before calling
> the Popup method programmatically to bring up the pop-up menu.

Comment: brilliant. I don't know why I don't get it. With that code you get the class from a first Level Item in the PopUp:
showmessage( TPopupMenu(TMenuItem(sender).GetParentComponent).PopupComponent.ClassName) ;
By the way I use Firmonkey application and it works too.

Comment: FMX should be mentioned somewhere. Otherwise everyone assumes VCL.

Comment: Especially since the question is tagged VCL and not Firemonkey

Comment: To be fair, the VCL and Firemonkey tags were applied later.